# Remotely manageable multi language support on android

Tags: android, json, firebase, kotlin, multilingual

I want to be able to modify a language file without publishing a new release of apk.

I've used paid tools for this localization issues before. I 'm trying to handle it without a product or tools.

Can I do this myself? I want to use a json language file that I received from the service as a key value in my android application.

For example, after selecting the language on the login page, I think I can download this language json file to my locale and use it as a language file.

How reliable is it? how performance is?

There is a firebase remote config, but I guess it is not used much for this purpose. Please write your suggestions..

Comment: `Can I do this myself?` why not ? what have you tried ? `How reliable is it? how performance is?` this is largely going to depend on how you implement it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase remote confis is actually a perfect use case for this +  a/b testing of your features.

There are alternatives as well but none with more documentation than remote config.

The logic how i have seen done is having a multimodule project and all resources accessed from a vernacular module . The remote config to switch between the languages.

I believe this can be achieved by 2 localized string files as well and use remote config to switch between them
.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the languages as json and save it locale in HashMap where is the key is the same keys in your stings file .. and create extension function called `getCustomString(stringName: String)` at this method you first check the hashMap if there is a value which is downloaded and parsed from json you return it .. if not you can get the default value in strings file with the following code

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getCustomString(stringName: String): String {
return if (yourMap.containsKey(stringName)) {
    yourMap[stringName]
} else {
    val resId = resources.getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName)
    getString(resId)
}
}
```